# Python Crypto\Cipher\_DES.pyc DLL load failed, how can I tell whic DLL?

Tags: python, dll, des, pycrypto

I am building a python application using the http://ftp.dlitz.net/pub/dlitz/crypto/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.6.tar.gz package, building it as a 32 bit application on a Windows 7 64-bit platform using MS Visual Studio 2010, and am exporting it as an executable using py2exe.
The executable runs fine on my Windows 7 platform.  However, when I try to run it on Windows Server 2008, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

- File "Crypto\Cipher\DES.pyc", line 54, in
- File "Crypto\Cipher_DES.pyc", line 12, in
- File "Crypto\Cipher_DES.pyc", line 10, in __load

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

The first problem that I want to overcome is that the pycrypto package does not include uncompiled python for _DES.pyc, so I have no idea what module it is trying to load.  Is there any way to find this out?  Note that if I comment out the calls to the Crypto routines, it also works fine, except that the functionality I want is missing :-)

Comment: You can try the pre-compiled binaries: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was to use pyDes instead, a pure python encryption package available at http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html.

Comment: Glad you've got it working, but I would find that more of a workaround than a direct solution to your problem.